# How to open ipynb files on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

How to open an **.ipynb** file on a Mac and use it?

Which apps is needed for that or what are your recommendations?

Comment: The `.ipynb` format is created by jupyterlab or jupyter notebook, so it can be used from a browser with Python+jupyter installed, regardless of windows or mac.

Comment: If you have `jupyter` installed then you can do `jupyter notebook myFile.ipynb` from the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

you need to install jupyter you can do it using: `pip install jupyter`
and run it in terminal with the command `jupyter notebook` this will open a browser window where you can view and run juputer notebooks

You can also open these notebooks in pyCharm and Visual Studio Code (after installing the python extension from microsoft)

Answer (score 6):

You tagged this with [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) so I'm answering in the context of Visual Studio Code.

---

VS Code has support for creating, opening/viewing, and running Jupyter notebooks (**.ipynb** files). Check out their complete tutorial from the VS Code docs: [Working with Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_setting-up-your-environment).

> Visual Studio Code supports working with Jupyter Notebooks natively,
> as well as through [Python code files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py). This topic covers the native
> support available for Jupyter Notebooks and demonstrates how to:
>
> - Create, open, and save Jupyter Notebooks
> - Work with Jupyter code cells
> - View, inspect, and filter variables using the Variable explorer and Data viewer
> - Connect to a remote Jupyter server
> - Debug a Jupyter notebook

If you just want to view/open a **.ipynb** file, just open it in VS Code like any other file.

[image]

If it doesn't open like that and you get a "weird" JSON-like file, make sure the setting "Jupyter: Use Notebook Editor" is enabled.

```
"jupyter.useNotebookEditor": true
```

[image]

If you need to be running cells, you'll need to [setup your environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_setting-up-your-environment) and install the [Jupyter package](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/).

You can let VS Code do all the initial setup steps for you. Open or create a **.ipynb** file, and try to run any cell. If your environment is not yet setup, it will show an error:

[image]

So click on that Install button to let VS Code install all the dependencies on the [currently selected Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Or if you want to install it yourself, [select and activate an environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment), then:

```
$ pip install jupyter
```

Once the Jupyter package is now installed, you'll see that the "Jupyter Server" indicator at the top right is now activate. Now, you can run cells.

[image]

---

So basically, all you need to do is:

1. Install VS Code
2. Setup a Python environment

   - On mac OS, it already has Python 2 but I recommend not using that
   - Instead, I recommend installing Python 3 [via Homebrew](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/)
3. Install the Jupyter package
4. Select the Python environment (with the Jupyter package)
5. Open and edit **.ipynb** files

Answer (score 1):

To quickly view an .ipynb file you can use the [nbviewer-app](https://github.com/tuxu/nbviewer-app).

Installation via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install --cask jupyter-notebook-viewer
```

Alternatively, you can also download the app directly.

Starting with Mac OS Catalina, you might have to open a terminal and run

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Jupyter\ Notebook\ Viewer.app
```

after installation because the app is not notarized by Apple [[Source](https://github.com/tuxu/nbviewer-app/issues/23#issue-684488159)].